# Does Checkstyle provide quickfix possibilities?

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I implemented an extension plugin for checkstyle.

Now I have the task to add quickfixes for some checkstyle errors in eclipse.

Example: Add a final modifier if a class is public.

After several hours of research, I decided to ask this question in several forums because I won't be the only one with this wish/problem.

According to the documentation of checkstyle http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/, the plugin does not provide quickfixes for own implemented checks.

I did some research but I found nothing about how to add quickfixes for own checks.

Now the question: Is there a way to implement own quickfixes for eclipse?

I'm using version 5.6 of the checkstyle API and Eclipse 4.2.

Comment: If I remember correctly there is a 'apply checkstyle fixes' option when using the eclipse plugin

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Extending the eclipse-cs plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending.html) page.

From there you can download a *sample Check*.

The file is [here](http://eclipse-cs.cvs.sourceforge.net/) under the name `net.sf.eclipsecs.sample`

In `src\net\sf\eclipsecs\sample\checks` there is one `QuickFix Java code` and in base directory, in `plugin.xml` the following line is present, which enables the quickfix.

```
    <!-- This plugin provides custom quickfixes for Checkstyle problems. -->
    <extension
          point="net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.checkstyleQuickfixProvider">
    </extension>
```

You can download and refer that sample for your query. [Extending Check](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending_custom_checks.html) is described nicely there.